# Set follow button title after query from parse

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So my `_User` class looks like this :

[image: <code>_User</code> class]

In the followedPeople column i've saved the objectIds of the user which is followed by the current user. My whole query looks like this:

```
var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var followedPeople = [NSArray]()

func loadData() {

    self.followedPeople.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    self.data.removeAllObjects()

    var usersQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

        usersQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        usersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        if user.objectId == PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            if object["followedPeople"] == nil {
                                println("nil value")                                    
                            } else {
                                self.followedPeople.append(object.objectForKey("followedPeople")! as! NSArray)
                                println(self.followedPeople)
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.data.addObject(object)
                            println(self.data)
                        }
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure.
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, I'm saving the objectIds of all the users followed by the current user and i want to use those objectIds in the tableView so that if the user is in the `NSArray` then the follow button's title of those users should be "Unfollow", basically i'm trying to show the user if he's already following someone.. My tableView code is:

```
let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


    // Usernames and gender..

    myCell.fullName.text = userData.objectForKey("fullName") as! String!
    myCell.genderLabel.text = userData.objectForKey("gender") as! String!
    myCell.userTypeLabel.text = userData.objectForKey("userType") as! String!

    // Profile pictures..

    let profilePics = userData.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile
    profilePics.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.dp.image = downloadedImage
        }

    }

    // here i want to set the button title..like:
    // if current user is following the user on the cell {
    //      myCell.followButton.setTitle("following", .normal)
    //   } else {
    //      myCell.followButton.setTitle("follow", .normal)
    // }

    myCell.createButton(self)

    return myCell
```

Comment: The question seems to be about setting a button title, but I don't see any button related code.

Comment: question is basically about saving the already followed users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you care about two arrays: (1) the array of all users, and (2) the array of users followed by the current user.

The find finds all users.  You logic after that find should change.  Just put all of the found users into the `data` array.

In cell for row at index path, you have...

```
let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
```

To determine whether that user is being followed by the current user, just check to see if that user's id is the followed users id array.  In pseudo-swift (I don't really speak it)...

```
var myFollowedUserIds = PFUser.currentUser["followedUsers"]
var userIsFollowed /* this is a bool */ myFollowedUserIds.containsObject(userData.objectId)
```

Now, configure the cell with `userIsFollowed`, saying things like...

```
var buttonTitle = userIsFollowed?  "Follow" : "Unfollow"
```

You might consider improving your design by keeping an array of pointers to actual followed users, rather than string ids in that followedUsers column.  One benefit is that they can be fetched eagerly when you get the current user.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that too, But i guess there are some limitations for counting the pointers ? Am i right?

Comment: could you help me to improve my design? What is the best possible way to save the followedUsers or followers?

Comment: The design improvement to which I referred is using pointers rather than string ids in the array.  There's no distinction for those relative to counts or limits. The benefit of pointers is that the actual object pointed to can be achieved when the object with the pointer is retrieved. See query includeKey.

Comment: Also, doing a get on all users will be untenable eventually. Imagine doing that on Facebook. You'll want some user search input to qualify the get.