# How to compare to arrays whether the objects of one array are there in the other or not

Tags: swift

let say we have:

```
 var a = ["z", "x"]
 var b = ["z", "x", "c", "d"]
```

now i want to check whether objects of array `a` are there in array `b` or not..
thanks for your time..

Comment: Do you want to know whether any item is in both, all items are in both, or which items are in both?

Comment: `intersect` the arrays...

Comment: i want to compare like a boolean value.. i want to store it like.. `[true,false,true,false]` "a" is there in `b` so true, there b is not in a , so false.. this type of thing.. hope u understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `map` in combination with `contains`:

```
let matches = map(a) { return contains(b, $0) }
```

`contains` checks to see if an item is in a collection

`map` is used to convert one array into another array with an element-by-element mapping.

As pointed out by @marcos, there are similar variants to answer the any and all questions as well

```
let any = a.reduce(false) { acc, item in return acc || contains(b, item) }
let all = a.reduce(true) { acc, item in return acc && contains(b, item) }
```

Comment: Also, `c.reduce(true, combine: { $0 && $1 })` will tell you if all objects from `a` are contained in `b`

Comment: Yeah, there's a number of variants depending on whether you're looking for any, all, or which.

Comment: i used this :` var a = ["1", "7", "4"]
var b = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
let matches = map(a) { return contains(b, $0) }
println(matches)` println give me "[true, false, true]" i need this [true.false,false,true] . Sorry i am unable to explain my problem clearly.

Comment: Just reverse the arrays then, you're wanting to test which elements of b exist in a, it looked to me like you wanted which elements of a exist in b.  Use `map(b) { return contains(a, $0) }`

Comment: actually i am trying to solve this problem @DavidBerry but i am stucked here.. :-| , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311483/set-follow-button-title-after-query-from-parse?noredirect=1#comment52501763_32311483

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `map`:

```
var a = [1, 7, 5, 2]
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let d = a.map { b.contains($0) }
print(d) // [true, false, false, true]
```

Comment: @AkshayKheveria It also should work with `[String]` - just replace `Int`s in array to your `String`s.

Comment: doesn't work.. giving me this error : `'String' does not have a member named 'contains'`

Comment: @AkshayKheveria this code work for me:  
  
    `var a = ["1", "7", "5", "2"]  
    var b = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]  
    let d = a.map { b.contains($0) }  
    print(d) // [true, false, false, true]`

Comment: @AkshayKheveria what version of Swift you use?

Comment: @AkshayKheveria [David Berry answered to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360601/how-to-compare-to-arrays-whether-the-objects-of-one-array-are-there-in-the-other/32360780#comment52596078_32360769)

Answer (score 2):

I think this following code snippet wil work:

```
var booleanArray = [Bool]()
for x in a{
    if !contains(b, x){
        booleanArray.append(false)
    }
    else{
        booleanArray.append(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for in loop and then use the array contains function:

Swift 2.0

```
var resultsArray : [Bool] = [Bool]()

let a = ["a","b","c"]
let b = ["a","c"]

for letter in a {

if b.contains(letter) == true {

    // Letter exists in a array
    resultsArray.append(true)

} else {

    // Letter does not exist in a array
    resultsArray.append(false)

}

}
```

Swift 1.2

Replace b.contains(letter) with:

```
contains(b, letter)
```

Comment: how can i save it in a set or array like [true,false,true] ??

Comment: Added a resultsArray that can track true, false to my answer

Comment: it just give ["true, false"] but i need [true,false,true] if we are checking b in a

Comment: just flip true and false then inside of the if statement.

Comment: you dint get me i guess.. i need the result to be saved in an Array `[Bool]()`
so basically i need it to be like, check b in a.. so we check all the values in the array b. we get "a" and "c" from there, then where these values would be in array `a` at that index i need to save true else save false.. the result array i need would be [true,false,true]

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the arrays to `Set` to use the `intersect` method

```
let a = ["a","c"]
let b = ["a","b","c","d"]
let aSet = Set(a)
let bSet = Set(b)
let intersection = aSet.intersect(bSet) // ["a", "c"]
```